# Handling oversized tables within containers

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

**Description**

I have difficulty adjusting the size of the table to fit properly within its container, both for thead and tbody. I want to create a table like this.

[image]

**Problem**

The problem is I struggle to arrange and adjust the number of items in both thead and tbody. Even when it's adjusted, the table's format is quite messy.

[image]

**What have I tried?**

I have tried using the property tableLayout: fixed; with width: 100%. However, the result is still messy.

**Question**

How can we handle this table layout issue? Is there a way to adjust the size of the table, both for thead and tbody (as shown in the UI image)?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Code**

```
const TableWorkOrder = ({ defaultValuesHeader, defaultValuesBody }) => {
  return (
    <Table style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word', whiteSpace: 'nowrap', tableLayout: 'fixed', width: '100%' }}>
      <thead>
        <tr className='txt-blue-grey-700'>
          {defaultValuesHeader.map((value, index) => (
            <th key={index} style={{ width: '20%' }}>
              {value}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {defaultValuesBody.map((value, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td style={{ width: '10%' }}>{value.no}</td>
            <td>
              <td><FaCheck color='#40B4BA'/></td>
              <td><FaCheck color='#40B4BA'/></td>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Link to={`/apotik/peresepan-rawat-inap/work-order-ri/${value.id}`}>
                <ButtonPrimary variant="solid"><FaMortarPestle/></ButtonPrimary>
              </Link>
            </td>
            <td><ButtonSecondary variant="solid"><FaPrint/></ButtonSecondary></td>
            <td><ButtonSecondary variant="solid"><FaPrint/></ButtonSecondary></td>
            <td><ButtonSecondary variant="solid"><FaPrint/></ButtonSecondary></td>
            <td>{value.tgl_masuk}</td>
            <td>{value.no_rm}</td>
            <td className={`${styles.linkNamaPasien}`}>{value.nama_lengkap}</td>
            <td>{value.dokter}</td>
            <td>{value.asal_pasien}</td>
            <td>{value.nasabah}</td>
            <td>{value.ambil_obat === "Sudah Bayar" ? <ButtonPrimary variant="solid">Ambil</ButtonPrimary> : <span className='text-danger'>Belum Dibayar</span>}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  )
}
```

also thead and tbody data :

```
import moment from "moment/moment";

const date = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');

const theadWorkOrder = [
    "No",
    "Persiapan Mulai|Selesai",
    "Penyiapan Obat",
    "Mini Resep",
    "Resep",
    "HTKP",
    "Tanggal Resep",
    "No. RM",
    "Nama Lengkap",
    "Dokter",
    "Asal Pasien",
    "Nasabah",
    "Ambil Obat"
];

let i = 0;

const tbodyWorkOrder = [
    {
        id: 1,
        no: i++,
        tgl_masuk: date,
        no_rm: "44244",
        nama_lengkap: "Udin Sholehatun",
        dokter: "dr. Ros Noor",
        asal_pasien: "Klinik Gigi",
        nasabah: "swasta",
        ambil_obat: "Belum Bayar"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        no: i++,
        tgl_masuk: date,
        no_rm: "442445",
        nama_lengkap: "Aris Angen",
        dokter: "dr. Ros Noordin",
        asal_pasien: "Klinik Dalam",
        nasabah: "swasta",
        ambil_obat: "Sudah Bayar"
    }
];

export { theadWorkOrder, tbodyWorkOrder };
```

Comment: One option is if you like, you can style container as overflow:auto so that content within container can scroll horizontally.